# Delete row on whats in the column code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete items from my data set. 
It basically says "go to columns B:V and look for my parameters, and if those values are in the columns, then delete the row.

Unfortunately, this code is not working, and I don't know why.

I tried breaking up the code to do the loop by 1 column, but that code was taking way to long to complete, I could have deleted the data faster myself.

Any thoughts?

```
Sub SellThrough_dataManip()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim strAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("B:V")
        Set rCell = .Find(What:="Check" & "CNL" & "TENA" & "cancelled" & "N" & "Z" & "R" & "Y" & "Club" & "#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            Do
                strAddress = rCell.Address
                rCell.EntireRow.Delete
                Set rCell = .FindNext(Range(strAddress))
            Loop Until rCell Is Nothing
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you are searching for the word "CheckCNLTENAcancelledNZRYClub#N/A" ... i doubt that you will find it  ... record a macro of doing the find command, the edit the resulting code

Comment: I am trying to find the words “check” “tena” “cancelled” etc inside columns b:v and then delete the rows which have those words in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try building up the range to be deleted in a loop and then delete everything in one go

```
Sub SellThrough_dataManip()
    Dim rCell As Range, DelRng As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("B:V")
        Set rCell = .Find(What:="Check" & "CNL" & "TENA" & "cancelled" & "N" & "Z" & "R" & "Y" & "Club" & "#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rCell.Address
            Do
                If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRng = rCell
                Else
                    Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, rCell)
                End If
                Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
            Loop While Not rCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it. After seeing jsotola's comment are you trying to find any of those terms? If so `Find` does not work that way